# Camunda and NestJs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, camunda

I am using the [camunda-external-task-client-js](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-external-task-client-js) in a project with NestJs and TypeScript and I have this problem:

```
D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.controller.js:18
const camunda_external_task_client_js_1 = require("camunda-external-task-client-js");
                                          ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\node_modules\camunda-external-task-client-js\index.js from D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.controller.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.controller.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.controller.js:18:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\app.module.js:11:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Practices\Camunda\NestJs4\dist\main.js:4:22)
```

I have tried to fix it by changing the package.json, the tsconfig.json and even the way the library is consumed but nothing works. Is there any way to fix the bug and/or run it together with a NestJs project?

Start the project and get the library working

Comment: same issue as any other ESM-only package when using with CJS nodejs projects, not related with nestjs itself. Do some searching here. There are several questions like this.

Comment: You may try using version 2.3.1 of camunda-external-task-client-js. I have a working example in one of my git repos.

https://github.com/freddycoder/Keycloak-Camunda/tree/main/camunda-worker

I like to better understand the problem and be able to install the latest version of the camunda-external-task-client-js in the future.